# Why changes to element stored by reference in a class "instance" object do not immediately reflect in (Firefox) code inspector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, render, web-inspector

The title says it all, really.  I wasted a lot of time chasing down what I thought was strange behavior using the debugger / inspector in Firefox, but it may just be a rendering timing issue, or my lack of experience with code inspector.  I'd like to work around it.  Consider this simplified code example:

```
class Folder
{
   constructor (tabCount)
   {
      this.tabs = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < tabCount; i += 1)
      {
         const me = document.createElement('DIV');
         this.tabs[i] = me;
         this.tabs[i].className = "tab";
         document.body.appendChild(this.tabs[i]);
      }

      selectTab(index)
      {
         this.tabs[index].classList.add('selected');
      }
   }
}
var mainFolder = new Folder(5);
mainFolder.selectTab(0);

//with CSS to give .tab red color and .tab.selected a blue color.
```

I set a Debugger break point at selectTab().  While paused and stepping, this.tabs[0].classList.add("selected") causes the expected color change in the document, but over in the HTML Inspector tab the class remains "tab" only.  Same thing if I alter in the console window with mainFolder.tabs[0].classList.add("selected").  As soon as I resume live code execution, the HTML inspector updates.

This is killing my ability to trace why ultimately my real code is assigning some CSS classes in error - I can't locate exactly in code when it happens because these particular class changes only have an observed impact downstream which isn't immediately visualized.  Does anybody know of a way to refresh, or re-render, or otherwise make (even better keep) up-to-date the HTML changes while paused in debug mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Please take the time before posting to ensure you don't have basic errors in the code (when you're not asking about those errors). In the above, you're missing the closing `}` on the constructor, which combined with your indentation makes it look like `selectTab` is declared *inside* the constructor, and `New` should be `new`.

Comment: I respect that - I did re-read it several times.  The original code was, I thought, hopelessly more complicated than the question needed so I was trimming it on the fly.  I stare at code long enough and some things just disappear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I was skeptical about the description of the problem, but sure enough, just tried Firefox v91 and the Inspector tab in the devtools doesn't seem to get updated as you step through the code.

I don't know that you really have anything you can do about it within Firefox, you might want to use another browser for debugging if this is problematic for you. [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home)'s devtools update as you go in the scenario you describe, for instance, and I suspect (if you use Windows) Microsoft Edge's would as well.